# Can't click a button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, test-strategy, debugging

I have this code:
[image]

I have a problem `clicking a button`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Editează'])[20]/following::a[1]").click()
```

And I receive this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Editează'])[20]/following::a[1]"}
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.86)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in xPath, but my understanding is that

```
.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Editează'])[20]
```

will lead you to the **20th element** with *Editează*.
In this case, it is already a link (***a*** tag).

Therefore, `/following::a[1]` will try to find a link inside a link - which leads to a failure.

Maybe only

```
//a[text()='Editează'][20]
```

will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the last td of the last tr of the table, I would recommend using

```
//table/tr[last()]/td[last()]/a[contains(@href,'edit')]
```

Especially if the website is multilanguage, and you are not trying to check the text of the button, but trying to achieve the edit action